# unable to upload two files in php

Tags: php

I want to upload the files in html as follow :

```
<tr><td><?php _e("Upload Trust Logo","emarksheet"); ?></td><td><label class="btn btn-danger" for="file-sel"><input id="file-sel" type="file" name="imaget" style="display:none;" size="25" />Browse to Upload Logo ....</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php _e("Upload Institute Logo","emarksheet"); ?></td><td><label class="btn btn-primary" for="file-sel2"><input id="file-sel2" type="file" name="image" style="display:none;" size="25" />Browse to Upload Logo ....</label></td></tr>
```

Two upload these files. My php code is as follow :

```
$path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
    $file = $_FILES['image'];
    //print_r($_FILES);
    $name1 = $file['name'];
    $type = $file['type'];
    $size = $file['size'];
    $tmppath = $file['tmp_name']; 
    move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, $path.'logos/'.$name1);
    //upload data end

    //upload trust logo`
    $file2 = $_FILES['imaget'];
    //print_r($_FILES);
    $name2 = $file2['name'];
    $type2 = $file2['type'];
    $size2 = $file2['size'];
    $tmppath2 = $file2['tmp_name']; 
    move_uploaded_file ($tmppath2, $path.'logos/'.$name2);
```

When I upload the files. The file name with `$name2` is uploaded but the file with name `$name1` is not uploaded

Please help why it not be uploaded

Comment: Check first using `print_r($_FILES)` what values are coming.

Comment: when I change ID `file-sel2` to `file-sel` then I am getting 'Array ( [imaget] => Array ( [name] => IMG_20151020_205510.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => E:\wamp\tmp\php803D.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 2706889 ) [image] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) '

Comment: else it is blank array

Comment: did you use any js for uploading or simple post method ..?

Comment: and change the file name `image` to something else like `imagem`.

Comment: no I have not used any js

Comment: why you hide the `<input>` tag...?

Comment: You have to use different name for input tags or you can use array likes names `image[]`;

Answer (score 2):

As you posted, the 'image' image has an error 4 code. That means no file was uploaded, as seen here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Why?

Since you are getting info in $_FILES, then you are not posting a total amount of data larger than the post_max_size php.ini directive, as, in this case, $_FILE would be completelly empty.

Then, maybe the php.ini upload_max_filesize, the maximum size for a singe file, is exceeded or the max_file_uploads is set to one, as max_file_uploads is the maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously.

Check those params at http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php and in your php.ini file.

I tried this snippet in my localhost server, and placed in [www_root]/tests/uploads/test1.php (note I just used the relevant part for our case):

```
<?php
if (empty($_FILES)) {
    echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' action='http://localhost/tests/uploads/test1.php'>";
    echo '<input id="file-sel" type="file" name="imaget" size="25" />';
    echo '<input id="file-sel2" type="file" name="image" size="25" />';
    echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
} else {
     echo print_r($_FILES);
}
```

And both files where correctly uploaded. Then the problem must be in the PHP configuration, not in the actual PHP code.

My values in php.ini:

1. post_max_size=8M
2. upload_max_filesize=2M
3. max_file_uploads=20

This means I can upload 20 files at the same time, but they can not exceed 8M in total nor an individual file can exceed 2M.

EDIT: after modifying the php.ini file, the server must be restarted in order to get those new values loaded.

Hope it helps.